# This NFSS system isn't set up properly

Tags: fonts, errors

I encountered a problem when i compile my tex file. Indeed, the compiler displays this  error messages:

```
 This NFSS system isn't set up properly
 Corrupted NFSS tables \ maketitle
 Math formula deleted: insufficie, t symbol fonts
```

I added the file kpfonts.sty but This operation has not resolved the problem

Comment: That means there is an error in a document you have not shown us. It is impossible to say more unless you generate a small example document that shows the problem. Start from a copy of your document and delete all text and packages that you can while still generating this error, then edit the question to include resulting document.

Comment: I got this error when forcibly updating texlive in Ubuntu running on Travis using the Ubuntu packages. I stopped that approach and went ahead by creating [a docker image](https://github.com/koppor/docker-texlive). Currently, this image is based on [sumdoc/texlive2017](https://hub.docker.com/r/sumdoc/texlive-2017/).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, that is right. I didn't read the error carefully. I will delete my comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: It might be there is a font-package missing. I recommend to provide a MinimalWorking example (*.tex-file) and the complete *.log-file.

Answer (score 10):

You seem to be using some nonstandard math fonts, probably some package that is supposed to set them up, but the corresponding support files that provide the right kind of information to the NFSS system aren't on your machine or can't be loaded for some other reason. In other words prior to that error that you listed, there should have been earlier errors or warnings that would/could give a hint of what is going wrong.

Basically if you intended to use a different font setup it is not enough to add a package you also need to ensure that

- the fonts are on your system (in a place where they are found by the engine)
- the corresponding .fd (font definition files) are on the system

If the latter are not found then NFSS will try for substitutes but especially with math involved those often do not work well and so you'll get this kind of error just before the engine gives up